# Raspberry Pi 2: HDMI resolution to 1280x1024 60 hz

Tags: hdmi, config.txt

I tried setting the resolution 1280x1024 60hz unsuccessfully in Debian Jessie ([AlienDeb](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=101831))

I use the config `/boot/firmware/config.txt`:

```
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_drive=2 
hdmi_group=2 
hdmi_mode=35
hdmi_force_hotplug=1 
config_hdmi_boost=4 
disable_overscan=1
```

[image: Screen Monitor]

But the screen does not seem to work.
Someone can help me?

Comment: And you are sure the display can accept this mode?  What other modes have you tried?  Do they all not work, or just this one?

Comment: What do you get if you run the following commands? `tvservice -d edit.out` then `edidparser edid.out` to parse the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me to set `raspberry_pi raspbian(jessie)` video resolution as `1280x1024`, from `655x500`(some very large and disturbing display resolution) I have made following changes in my `/boot/config.txt` file.

***PS : These are the only values in my `/boot/config.txt`***

```
disable_overscan=1

hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa50000080
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=36
```

Using following commands we can get the available [hdmi_mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=25933), and I have picked up the one I needed.

```
tvservice -m CEA
tvservice -m DMT
```

**Attached screenshots of two display:**

Before changing in default configuration (hdmi_mode=4) my display was as below:

[image: 655x555 resolution]

After changing the configurations as per above it turned up like as below:

[image: 1280x1024 resolution]

Its a late reply, but still hope these info might help someone.